# Чи потрібно ставити кому між посадою, статусом та iм'ям?

Tags: пунктуація

Добрий вечір!
Чи потрібна кома у словосполученні "студент 2 курсу Комп'ютерної інженерії, Круш Артур"?

Наскільки я пам'ятаю, в одному порядку у послідовності ім'я - статус кома ставиться, у іншому - ні.

Comment: Вітаємо вас у міжнародній експертній спільноті з обміну знань StackExchange!  Гілка з вивчення української мови є вільним співтовариством однодумців. Спільними зусиллями ми намагаємось знаходити тут відповіді на найскладніші запитання і дотримуватись високих стандартів якості, щоб бути відповіді лишались корисними ще довгий час. Ви можете уточнювати та покращувати ваші запитання і відповіді використовуючи меню редагування Edit.

Comment: Ви можете уточнити в якому типі документу і в якій позиціі хочете використати наведену фразу, щоб отримати більш точну відповідь на запитання саме для вашого випадку.

Answer (score 1):

## І. Кома в простому реченні

**[Український правопис § 158. КОМА (,)](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf)**

У простому реченні кому ставимо в таких позиціях.

1. Між однорідними членами речення, не поєднаними сполучниками:

> **Примітка 3.** Прикладки є однорідними, коли вони, як і звичайні означення, характеризують предмет з якогось одного боку або вказують
> на різні близькі, суміжні його ознаки, напр.: *Доктор філологічних
> наук, професор І. Петренко* (науковий ступінь і вчене звання).
>
> Якщо ж вони характеризують предмет цілком очевидно з різних боків, вони не є однорідними й між ними не ставимо коми: *завідувач кафедри
> української мови доктор філологічних наук І. Петренко* (посада й
> науковий ступінь).
>
> У разі поєднання в одному ряду однорідних і неоднорідних прикладок >відповідно розставляються й розділові знаки:
> *завідувач кафедри української мови доктор філологічних наук, професор І. Петренко*.
>
> Але прикладки, що стоять після означуваного
> іменника, відокремлюються комами незалежно від їхнього змістового
> навантаження: *І. Петренко, завідувач кафедри української мови,
> доктор філологічних наук, професор*.